# Handbook of Categorical Algebra Definition 1.1.2

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the definition mentioned in the title, an universe $\mathcal U$ is defined as a set satisfying some properties. One of this properties is that if $x\in \mathcal U$ and $f: x\to y$ is surjective then $y\in \mathcal U$. Another property asserts that $\{\emptyset\} \in \mathcal U$. Doesn't this imply that no universe exists? Consider the function $f:\{\emptyset\}\to\{\mathcal U\}$. This implies $\{\mathcal U\}\in \mathcal U$ which contradicts the axiom of regularity. Am i correct, and if so, what did the author mean to say instead?

Comment: You've tacitly assumed $\mathcal U \in\mathcal U$ when you defined the function.

Comment: @CyclotomicField No? If $\mathcal U$ exists then certainly the function i defined exists, and its domain is in $\mathcal U$. I don't understand what makes you say that.

Comment: $\mathcal U $ exists but $\{\mathcal U\}$ doesn't. If you allow Quine atoms (urelements) regularity does fail.

Comment: @CyclotomicField If $\mathcal U$ exists then the axiom of pairing implies that $\{\mathcal U\}$ also exists. This book defines $\mathcal U$ as a set.

Comment: Then regularity fails. Quine atoms are incompatible with it.